# DHCP Failover works but no DNS available

Tags: domain-name-system, dhcp, failover

I have a DHCP failover (load balance) configured. DHCP failover works but the clients are not getting any DNS entries.

We have 2 DNS servers using AD-integrated zones, and the failover is between these two servers. However, when I created the DHCP Failover and tested it, I noticed that clients were only getting IPv6 DNS entries, this is a big NO for us. Based on this, I disabled IPv6 from all the NIC cards and also removed them from the DNS "Listen on" under the server properties in DNS manager. This did not work either, the clients didn't get anything at all.

I then created a VM, installed AD, DHCP failover works but no DNS entries.

How can I get AD to serve DNS with DHCP failover?

Comment: Having not used DHCP failover yet, my first question would be: have you verified that the server you failed over to is configured with DNS servers to assign to the clients (under your IPv4 scope options and/or under Server options).

Comment: I am confused why you would have disabled IPv6.  I don't see how doing that would fix/change a DNS problem.  Are you publishing the same DNS servers on both DHCP servers?  Do all the DNS servers return valid responses to queries when you aren't testing your failover state?

Comment: Is the IPv6 entry "::1" by any chance? As a side node: do not disable IPv6 on your server network cards. This is most likely the wrong solution (http://blogs.technet.com/b/netro/archive/2010/11/24/arguments-against-disabling-ipv6.aspx)

Comment: Daniel,Yes, the IPv6 is ::1. However, we are not using IPv6 at all. Further more, When I disable the IPv6 IPs on the PDC, the clients do not get anything at all when I test the failover. Clients DO get IPv4 address in normal operational state. As I mentioned before, clients do get an IP, just not DNS entries or IPv6 DNS addresses. This is driving me crazy.

Comment: Zoredache, I disabled IPv6 so these addresses are not published as DNS addresses. This was an attempt to force the DNS server to just use IPv4, but when I test the failover, clients do not get any DNS IPs if IPv6 IPs are disabled at the server.